# Return Custom ValidationResult and access it from controller in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-validation

I'm writing a custom validation attribute for validating the model and I need some additional information other than what `ValidationResult` offers. I need to return `ErrorMessage` and `ErrorCode` and access it in the controller class so that I can send it in the response payload.

```cs
public class CustomValidationResult : ValidationResult
{
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }

    protected CustomValidationResult(ValidationResult validationResult) : base(validationResult)
    {
    }
}

public class Mandatory : RequiredAttribute
{
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        ErrorCode = 10;

        var result = base.IsValid(value, validationContext);

        ErrorCode = 10;

        return new CustomValidationResult(result)
        {
            ErrorCode = ErrorCode
        };
    }
}
```

I need to get the ErrorCode out in the controller, if `ModelState.IsValid` fails.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried putting a [TryCatch block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) around base.IsValid

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: What will you deal with `ErrorCode` if `ModelState.IsValid` fails? It is impossible to extend `class property`, and you could not custom `ValidationResult` which is defined in `ValidationAttribute`. For a workaound, I suggest you try to store error code in error message like `[Required(ErrorMessage ="[400]Name is required")]`, and then get `Error Code 400` from `ErrorMessage`.

Comment: Thank you @Edward. I am already doing a workaround. I was trying to know if there is a right and neater way of doing this.

Comment: When will you use `ErrorCode`? Do you only use this in `Controller` like `ModelState.IsValid`, or you will use it in the `View`? If later, I am afriad it is impossible. If previous, you may consider define static class to valide the model by your self instead of using `ModelState.IsValid`. Anyway, it is also complex. I am wondering whether this `ErrorCode` is requrired since I did not see any meaning for it while validing Model.

Comment: The `ErrorCode` is used while sending the response to the client. (It's a WebApi), so yes, I use it in Controller. For now, I'm adding the `ErrorCode` and `ErrorMessage` to a list in `RequestContext` class from a `CustomValidationAttribute`. I was hoping to get a neater approach as I have concerns with Single Responsibility Principle.

Answer (score -1):

From a controller you can return  for eg:- if

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
{
return BadRequest(ModelState)
}
```

If the Model is decorated with ErrorMessage, for eg:

```
Class TypeA
{

[Required[ErrorMessage="Should not be null"]]
public string Name;

}
```

The error message will be returned when the model state is returned as part of the BadRequest.

If you  have any custom validation , error can be added to the ModelState as below from the controller API:

for eg:-

```
if(typeA.Name == "TestName")
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Name","TestName is not a valid name.");
}
```