# Return Custom ValidationResult and access it from controller ModalState in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, data-annotations, modelstatedictionary

I have same issue as mentioned in this question long back.
[Return Custom ValidationResult and access it from controller in Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51818978/return-custom-validationresult-and-access-it-from-controller-in-asp-net-core)

But it didn't concluded with an answer.
Please suggest a way to get CustomValidationResult into ModelState of controller.
Note: I am not trying to create new action filters. i am trying to work with ValidationResult, ValidationAttribute and ModelState.

i created a class for

```
CustomValidationResult : ValidationResult
```

Using this in my custom attribute

```
Mandatory : RequiredAttribute
```

This is not reflecting back to controller level ModelState for further validation.

Comment: could you pls give more details? such as you followed which tutorial to try to do something, then you met some error/not work as expected/..., you already tired something...